# Navigating webview with the textbox

Tags: c#, debugging, uwp

I just want to make a simple web browser app.

So, I have this textbox and a webview but its giving me an error when I run it on this line:

```
if(e.Key.ToString()=="Enter")
{
    webview.Navigate(new Uri(textBlock.Text,ToString());
}
```

Comment: what kind of error, any exception message ? ",ToString()" should be ".ToString()"

Comment: Dont use e.key.ToString,you should `e.Key==VirtualKey.Enter`

Comment: Except the `.ToString()` as x... mentioned, I actually can't reproduce your problem, please provide more details, like code, exception info, even your program environment.